# Lightslider going reverse after last slide

Tags: javascript, slider, gallery

I'm using lightslider - v1.1.6 but it's going reverse after last slide.

After the last slide (2nd image) the slider is rotating reverse to the first image again. I want it to keep going to right direction, not returing back to first.

The issue is only happening in IE, but it's working fine on chrome.

JS File:

```
/*! lightslider - v1.1.6 - 2016-10-25
* https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider
* Copyright (c) 2016 Sachin N; Licensed MIT */
(function ($, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var defaults = {
        animationLoop: false,
        item: 2,
        autoWidth: false,
        slideMove: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        addClass: '',
        mode: 'slide',
        useCSS: true,
        cssEasing: 'ease', //'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
        easing: 'linear', //'for jquery animation',//
        speed: 400, //ms'
        auto: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        loop: false,
        slideEndAnimation: true,
        pause: 2000,
        keyPress: false,
        controls: true,
        prevHtml: '',
        nextHtml: '',
        rtl: false,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        vertical: false,
        verticalHeight: 500,
        vThumbWidth: 100,
        thumbItem: 10,
        pager: true,
        gallery: false,
        galleryMargin: 5,
        thumbMargin: 5,
        currentPagerPosition: 'middle',
        enableTouch: true,
        enableDrag: true,
        freeMove: true,
        swipeThreshold: 40,
        responsive: [],
        /* jshint ignore:start */
        onBeforeStart: function ($el) {},
        onSliderLoad: function ($el) {},
        onBeforeSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onAfterSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onBeforeNextSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onBeforePrevSlide: function ($el, scene) {}
        /* jshint ignore:end */
    };
    $.fn.lightSlider = function (options) {

                          .....
                          .....
                          .....
                          .....
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Here's the html file.

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
        <div class="item">            
            <div class="clearfix" style="max-width:474px;">
                <ul id="image-gallery" class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden">
                    <li> 
                        <img src="/img/banner_home1.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <img src="/img/banner_home2.jpg" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution to your problem, but you should not accomadate for any version of Internet Explorer. Microsoft strongly recommends a user-discontinuance of the Internet Explorer browser. Now if this issue exists in Edge, then you may have a legitimate concern.

Answer (score 0):

Set loop to true

```
/*! lightslider - v1.1.6 - 2016-10-25
* https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider
* Copyright (c) 2016 Sachin N; Licensed MIT */
(function ($, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var defaults = {
        animationLoop: false,
        item: 2,
        autoWidth: false,
        slideMove: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        addClass: '',
        mode: 'slide',
        useCSS: true,
        cssEasing: 'ease', //'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
        easing: 'linear', //'for jquery animation',//
        speed: 400, //ms'
        auto: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        loop: true,
        slideEndAnimation: true,
        pause: 2000,
        keyPress: false,
        controls: true,
        prevHtml: '',
        nextHtml: '',
        rtl: false,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        vertical: false,
        verticalHeight: 500,
        vThumbWidth: 100,
        thumbItem: 10,
        pager: true,
        gallery: false,
        galleryMargin: 5,
        thumbMargin: 5,
        currentPagerPosition: 'middle',
        enableTouch: true,
        enableDrag: true,
        freeMove: true,
        swipeThreshold: 40,
        responsive: [],
        /* jshint ignore:start */
        onBeforeStart: function ($el) {},
        onSliderLoad: function ($el) {},
        onBeforeSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onAfterSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onBeforeNextSlide: function ($el, scene) {},
        onBeforePrevSlide: function ($el, scene) {}
        /* jshint ignore:end */
    };
    $.fn.lightSlider = function (options) {

                          .....
                          .....
                          .....
                          .....
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```